# Why is an error is generated when I type cast a pointer and subtract it?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, implicit-conversion

Why doesn't typecasting work here..?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
   int x = 5;
   float y = 7.0;
   float *p = &y;
   int *q = &x;
   printf("p is %d\nq is %d\np - q is %d", p, q, (p - q));
   return 0;  
  }
```

I am getting this error `invalid operands of types 'float*' and 'int*' to binary 'operator-'`; what does it mean?

Comment: It means that you can't subtract a pointer to `int` from a pointer to `float` because they point to different types. Also, what's the point of subtracting them anyway?

Comment: You don't have any typecast

Comment: Pointer comparisons are only valid when both pointers are pointers **to the same object** or one element past the end of **the same object**, where an object may be an array.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that the compiler is unable to deduce the common type of two operands one of which has the type `float *` and other `int *`. There is no implicit conversion between these types.

But in any case the program has undefined behavior because at least you may not subtract two pointers that do not point to elements of the same array or to a memory after the last element of the same array.

From the C Standard (6.5.6 Additive operators)

> 9 When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of
>   the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two
>   array elements.

And using incorrect conversion specifiers (as for example `%d` with a pointer) for supplied arguments in the function `printf` also invokes undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> 9 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.275) **If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.**

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to subtract the actual values your pointers are pointing to.
C converts `int` to `float` implicitly when you are operating on `float` and `int`.

Also, you program has some problems as

- Not using `%f` type specifier to print `float` pointer
- Not using the `*` operator to access pointer values.

Here is your program, working:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    float y = 7.0;
    float *p = &y;
    int *q = &x;
    printf("p is %f\nq is %d\np - q is %f", *p, *q, (*p - *q));
    return 0;
}
```

With the outputs:

```sh
p is 7.000000
q is 5
p - q is 2.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't subtract pointers like that and get a meaningful result in standard C.

Per [**6.5.6 Additive operators**, paragraph 9 of the C11 standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p9):

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements.

In this case, a single `int` or `float` variable is considered to be an array of size `1`.

So given

```
int x = 5;
float y = 7.0;
float *p = &y;
int *q = &x;
```

trying to compute the value `p - q` results in undefined behavior.

Per [**J.2 Undefined behavior**](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2):

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> ...
>
> - Pointers that do not point into, or just beyond, the same array object are subtracted

However, code like this likely won't cause problems as it's merely subtracting two integer values (although I haven't checked thoroughly), but the result doesn't have to be meaningful:

```
int x = 5;
float y = 7.0;
float *p = &y;
int *q = &x;

intptr_t diff = ( intptr_t ) p - ( intptr_t ) q;
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: As has been pointed out in the comments, subtracting two void* pointers is not proper standard C. If you want to subtract two pointers to find the distance between them the correct approach is to cast them to an appropriately sized integer, and then do integer arithmetic.

E.g.:

`printf("p is %p\nq is %p\np - q is %ld\n", p, q, ((intptr_t)p - (intptr_t)q));`

Original answer:

It means that the minus operator is not defined for mixed types of pointers. If you want to subtract those two pointers, for example to find the amount of space between them, the better option would be to cast them both to `void*` pointers.

Also, you should print pointer values with the `%p` specifier instead of `%d`.

E.g.:

`printf("p is %p\nq is %p\np - q is %ld\n", p, q, ((void*)p - (void*)q));`

Comment: *the better option would be to cast them both to void\* pointers.*  **No**.  You can't do pointer arithmetic on `void *` pointers.  Some implementations offer that as a non-portable extension.

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to subtract two `void` pointers in standard C, though I think gcc allows it as an extension.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic on `void *` is a non-standard extension (introduced by GCC), so `char *` would be preferable for pointer arithmetic. (It's still technically undefined behavior to subtract pointers to different objects except within the same array, but it is likely to just display the difference in address values rather than blow up your computer on most implementations.)

Comment: @Ian Abbott, If one wants to treat the pointers as numbers, casting them into numbers (`uintptr_t`) makes more sense to me than casting them into `char*`.

Comment: Technically, the argument corresponding to `%p` needs to be a `void *`, rather than an `int *` or a `float *`.

Comment: @ikegami Or rather `intptr_t` since the result of subtraction could be negative.